# What is the difference between Count and Count() in observable collections in C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight

What is the difference between Count and Count() in observable collections in C#?
I have noticed in the type ahead of Visual Studio for the ObservableCollection class I can choose either ".Count;" or ".Count();".  What is the difference?  Not knowing this can get one in trouble, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Count()` is a LINQ extension. The `Count` is a property inherited from `Collection<T>`. The implementation of the `Count()` extension will know that your object is implementing `ICollection<T>`, and so will just return the results of the property. You can use either one, the performance benefit of using the property are basically non-existent.

Answer (score 2):

It does not really matter, but Count() is available on more types.

Not all collection types have a Count property. For example, an IEnumerable does not. The LINQ method Count() *does* work on all these collection types, either by using the Count property or looping through the collection to count the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Count is a ObservableCollection property, Count() is extension method from linq.